# Turn on screen without using any button on the phone

Tags: buttons, motorola, remote-access

**All buttons on the device are broken, device is on but the screen is off.**

Is there any way to turn on the phone using USB or any other  way?

My phone is a moto e20 with no removable battery and no removable case. I need to use my phone once before sending it to repair and since Google's "Find my device" tool lets you play sounds, lock your screen and erase all data, it might be possible to send the power button signal from external sources.

**Edit:** Fingerprint sensor won't work either since the device doesn't have any finger registered.

Comment: What about the fingerprint sensor? Is it working and is at least one finger learned? Besides that may be able to connect a simple USB mouse via USB and use the mouse buttons to wake the screen.

Comment: The device doesn't have a lock screen password and the fingerprint sensor has no finger learned.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** This solution only works if your phone is already on. Otherwise, your device will get locked and you'll have more difficulties.

After 2 hours of trial and error I discovered that using the Lock With Password"  otion on [this link](https://www.google.com/android/find?action=lockWithPassword) will activate your screen once. Don't forget to inmediatly unlock your device or it will get locked since it logs out from your Google Account.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).